# Replace words in text2vec efficiently

Tags: r, text2vec

I have a large text body where I want to replace words with their respective synonyms efficiently (for example replace all occurrences of "automobile" with the synonym "car"). But I struggle to find a proper (efficient way) to do this.

For the later analysis I use the `text2vec` library and would like to use that library for this task as well (avoiding `tm` to reduce dependencies).

An (inefficient) way would look like this:

```
# setup data
text <- c("my automobile is quite nice", "I like my car")

syns <- list(
  list(term = "happy_emotion", syns = c("nice", "like")),
  list(term = "car", syns = c("automobile"))
)
```

My brute-force solution is to have something like this and use a loop to look for the words and replace them

```
library(stringr)
# works but is probably not the best...
text_res <- text
for (syn in syns) {
  regex <- paste(syn$syns, collapse = "|")
  text_res <-  str_replace_all(text_res, pattern = regex, replacement = syn$term)
}
# which gives me what I want
text_res
# [1] "my car is quite happy_emotion" "I happy_emotion my car"
```

I used to do it with `tm` using this approach [by MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24443686/3048453) (using `tm::content_transformer` and `tm::tm_map`), but I want to reduce the dependencies of the project by replacing `tm` with the faster `text2vec`.

I guess the optimal solution would be to somehow use `text2vec`s `itoken`, but I am unsure how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite late, but still I want to add my 2 cents.
I see 2 solutions

1. Small improvement over your `str_replace_all`. Since it is vectorized internally you can make all replacements without loop. I think it will be faster, but I didn't make any benchmarks.

   ```
   regex_batch = sapply(syns, function(syn) paste(syn$syns, collapse = "|"))  
   names(regex_batch) = sapply(syns, function(x) x$term)  
   str_replace_all(text, regex_batch)
   ```
2. Naturally this task is for hash-table lookup. Fastest implementation as far as I know is in `fastmatch`package. So you can write custom tokenizer, something like:

   ```
   library(fastmatch)

   syn_1 = c("nice", "like")
   names(syn_1) = rep('happy_emotion', length(syn_1))
   syn_2 = c("automobile")
   names(syn_2) = rep('car', length(syn_2))

   syn_replace_table = c(syn_1, syn_2)

   custom_tokenizer = function(text) {
     word_tokenizer(text) %>% lapply(function(x) {
       i = fmatch(x, syn_replace_table)
       ind = !is.na(i)
       i = na.omit(i)
       x[ind] = names(syn_replace_table)[i]
       x
     })
   }
   ```

I would bet that second solution will work faster, but need to make some benchmarks.

Comment: That looks like a very interesting concept! I did some quick benchmarks on them. While on small synonym-samples, the for-loop is faster, the `fastmatch` approach is a lot faster on larger lists!
Also, as I am still working on the project, your 2 cents are very valuable here!

Comment: Also note, that `text2vec::word_tokenizer` is quite slow compared to `stringr::str_split(TEXT_HERE, pattern = stringr::boundary("word"))`. The only reason I'm not using `stringr`/`stringi`/`tokenizers` is that I want to keep number of `text2vec` dependencies as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

With base R this should work:

```
mgsub <- function(pattern,replacement,x) {
if (length(pattern) != length(replacement)){
    stop("Pattern not equal to Replacment")
} 
    for (v in 1:length(pattern)) {
        x  <- gsub(pattern[v],replacement[v],x)
    }
return(x )
}

mgsub(c("nice","like","automobile"),c(rep("happy_emotion",2),"car"),text)
```

Comment: Isn't this very similar to the loop I posted? Just replacing `stringr::str_replace_all` with `gsub`?

Comment: It is, but as you wanted to reduce dependencies I figured you wanted a base R solution. Have you checked out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273928/faster-approach-than-gsub-in-r) ?

Comment: I was aware of the `perl = T` (which indeed adds speed), and it seems to be faster than `stringr`. But still, I wonder if `text2vec` offers a faster alternative (by using the tokens...)

Answer (score 1):

The first part of solution by Dmitriy Selivanov requires a small change.

```
library(stringr)    

text <- c("my automobile is quite nice", "I like my car")

syns <- list(
             list(term = "happy_emotion", syns = c("nice", "like")),
             list(term = "car", syns = c("automobile"))
             )

regex_batch <- sapply(syns, function(syn) syn$term)  
names(regex_batch) <- sapply(syns, function(x) paste(x$syns, collapse = "|"))  
text_res <- str_replace_all(text, regex_batch) 

text_res
[1] "my car is quite happy_emotion" "I happy_emotion my car"
```