# Rename suffix part of column name but keep the rest the same

Tags: r, regex, rename, suffix

For now I am redoing a merge because I poorly named the columns, however, I would like to know how to match on a suffix of a column name and rename that part of the column, keeping the rest the same.

For example, if I have a data.frame (could be a data.table too, doesn't matter - I could convert it):

```
d <- data.frame("ID" = c(1, 2, 3),
                "Attribute1.prev" = c("A", "B", "C"),
                "Attribute1.cur" = c("D", "E", "F"))
```

Now imagine that there are hundreds of columns similar to columns 2 & 3 from my sample DT. How would I go through and detect all columns ending in `".prev"` change to `".1"` and all columns ending in `".cur"` change to `".2"`?

So, the new column names would be: `ID` (unchanged), `Attribute1.1`, `Attribute1.2` and so on for as many columns that match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base R we may do

```
names(d) <- sub("\\.prev", ".1", sub("\\.cur", ".2", names(d)))
d
#   ID Attribute1.1 Attribute1.2
# 1  1            A            D
# 2  2            B            E
# 3  3            C            F
```

With the `stringr` package you could also use

```
names(d) <- str_replace_all(names(d), c("\\.prev" = ".1", "\\.cur" = ".2"))
```

If instead of `Attribute1` and `Attribute2` you may have some names with dots/spaces, you could also replace `"\\.prev"` and `"\\.cur"` patterns to `"\\.prev$"` and `"\\.cur$"` as to make sure that we match them at the end of the column names.

Comment: Would `stringr` be faster?

Comment: Do you really need speed? 100s of columns should be negligible time spent. I just benchmarked a frame with 100,000 columns, and doing Julius' double-`dubsub` rename took less than 0.1 seconds. Your time might be spent focusing on more time-expensive operations.

Comment: @Bear, I agree with r2evans, but you may see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/29275120/1320535 to get an idea about speed differences.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea using `dplyr` & `stringr` syntax

```
library(dplyr); library(stringr)
names(d) <- 
  d %>% names() %>% 
  str_replace(".prev", ".1") %>% 
  str_replace(".cur", ".2")
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
names(d) <- gsubfn("(\\w+)", list(prev = 1, cur = 2), names(d))
names(d)
#[1] "ID"           "Attribute1.1" "Attribute1.2"
```